# I can able to find this file where?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used `writeToFile` to create input.txt file  , but without this file in the path of the project I don't know how can I find it.

```
NSString* str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr];
[str2 writeToFile:@"input.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString* str3 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"input.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: You need to pass a full path to `writeToFile:`. Then use the same full path when reading the file.

Comment: instead of @"input.txt" pass path of that file and than write to that file.

Comment: Your code will not work as posted. It will return an error and fail to save. As others have pointed out, you nee to pass a full path to the path parameter of `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`. Bori's answer, below, shows how to save your file to the app's documents directory, one of the limited number of places you can save files in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U need to add a path to your app Documents folder to your file:

```
//get path to Documents 
NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
//add path to you file name
NSString *fileWithPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"input.txt"];
//then write
[str2 writeToFile:fileWithPath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

then you will be able to read it back too using fileWithPath:

```
NSString* str3 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileWithPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (voted.)  To the OP, you should accept this answer.